# NodeJs error with asynchronous calling functions

Tags: node.js, email, callback, null, send

sorry for my english, i hope someone can help me, im trying to send template emails  using gmail as smtp, everything works ok in the same file server.js file, but im trying to separete in differents modules and im getting an error when call the same function, im getting a null error in debug mode

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.exports.sendmail (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/server.js:44:4)
    at exports.sendregistermail (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/controllers/mailing.js:25:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:109:7)
```

in console im getting

```
/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express-mailer/lib/express-mailer.js:81
          callback(null, res.message);
          ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at MailComposer.returnCallback (/src/react/impex/jumbo-react-flat/mailing/node_modules/express-mailer/lib/express-mailer.js:81:11)
```

My code

**server.js**

```
// call the packages we need
var express = require('express');  // call express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
path=require('path');
var app = express(); // create a server
var port = process.env.PORT || 8002;  // set our port
var mailer = require('express-mailer'); // call express
var promise = require('promise');


// set the view folder to views
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// set the view engine to pug
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route

// test route to trigger emails
// Configure express-mail and setup default mail data.
mailer.extend(app, {
  from: 'info@neptuno.ec',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // hostname
  secureConnection: true, // use SSL
  port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
  transportMethod: 'SMTP', // default is SMTP. Accepts anything that nodemailer accepts
  auth: {
    user: 'user', // gmail id
    pass: 'pass' // gmail password
  }
});



app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Escuchando en el puerto ${port}!`);
});

  // Send email.
  exports.sendmail = function (template, mailOptions) {
    app.mailer.send(template, mailOptions)
   .then(function (err) {
     debugger
      if (err) {
        return err;
      }
      return ;
    });
    }
```

**mailing.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var server = require('../server.js');
var Promise = require('promise');


exports.sendregistermail = function (req, res) {
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    // Setup email data.
    var mailOptions = {
      to: 'Polo@neptuno.ec',
      subject: 'Registro en Impex Flowers',
      user: { // data to view template
        name: 'Polo Onofa',
        thanks: 'Gracias por registrarte en impex FLowers',
        message: 'Un representante se comunicara contigo para completar tu registro'
      }
    }

    // Send email.

  server.sendmail('emailorden', mailOptions, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send('Ocurrio un error al enviar tu email');
      return;
    }
    return res.send('Email enviado correctamente!');
  });


  };
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: i cannot find any "then" in the documentation for module express-mailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mailer.send() is returning a callback not a promise so you cannot use .then() here. You should change your function as follows:

```
exports.sendmail = function (template, mailOptions) {
    app.mailer.send(template, mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (err)
            return err;
        return ;
    });
}
```

Far more important regarding your aim of restructuring your code: 
Since you're creating a module for sending mails, everything mail related should go in there. `mailer.extend()` as well as `sendmail()` should move there to. Make sure to pass your instance of `app` to the mailing.js so that you can initialize the express-mailer.